# Wordpress Custom File Permalink

Tags: customization, permalinks

Guys i have a custom file that is not part of the wordpress and its not a part of the plugins. How can i add it to the permalink solution? For example:

Custom file name - example123.php
Permalink solution - http://mysite.com/example

Comment: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-links-to/ Might help you. You can make a page so you get the mysite.com/example url, and then link the page's url to your file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make a template out of your file and then in WP create a page named "Example" to which you assign this template.